# Is it possible to import files from the standard lib location without specifying a full path?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to import `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts`, but I am currently specifying the fill path... I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
import <lib.es2015.core.d.ts>
```

Is it possible to point the compiler at a standard import path?

Comment: are you using systemjs??

Comment: What is systemjs? I am not using it.